# Calling a java script function in grid view button field

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, buttonfield

I have a asp.net grid view which has a buttonfield to reset a user? I need to call a js function to get a confirmation message, when the buttonfield clicks, Any ideas? TIA

here is my grid view

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdAllProducts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%" OnRowCommand="grdAllProducts_RowCommand">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="USER_ID" HeaderText="User ID" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="USER_NAME" HeaderText="User Name" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="EMAIL" HeaderText="E-mail" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PHONE_NUMBER" HeaderText="Phone No." />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="USER_ROLE_NAME" HeaderText="User Role" />
                            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Reset" />
                        </Columns>
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />
                    </asp:GridView>
```

**here is my js function**

```
function validateResetButton() {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to Reset this User?')) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This works for me...**

*Add commandname in buttonfield*

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Reset" CommandName="Reset" />
```

*Add rowdatabound to gridview control*

```
protected void  grdAllProducts_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        { 
            // if you dont want the for loop directly put the button index 
            for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
            { 
                foreach (Button button in e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.OfType<Button>())
                {
                    if (button.CommandName == "Reset")
                    {
                        button.Attributes["onclick"] = "if(!confirm('Do you want to Reset ?')){ return false; };";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in most cases, it MUCH easer to just drop in a regular plain jane button.

So, say we have this simple GV.

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" Width="50%"
            DataKeyNames="ID">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName"   HeaderText="FirstName"   />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName"    HeaderText="LastName"    />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City"        HeaderText="City"        />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName"   HeaderText="HotelName"   />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="cmdDel" runat="server" Text="Delete" CssClass="btn" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And code to load:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

And we now have this:

[image]

So, lets now add a click event to the button.

[image]

so, we have now this:

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="cmdDel" runat="server" 
            Text="Delete" 
            CssClass="btn"
            onclick="cmdDel_Click"
            onclientClick="return confirm('really delete this?');"
            />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And our code behind click event?

Say this:

```
    protected void cmdDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btnDel = (Button)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)btnDel.NamingContainer;

        // get PK id of row
        // (note how this is hidden - NEVER exposed client side
        int PKID = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"];

        Debug.Print("Row index click = " + gRow.RowIndex);
        Debug.Print("pk row id for click = " + PKID);

        string strSQL = "DELETE FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID =  @ID";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PKID;
                cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
     }
```